# Scalable opacity box HTML

Tags: html, css

I ran into a problem and can't find the answer.
We have Div1 with a gradient. It invested another DIV2 with the picture. It invested контент3 section.
Setting the opacity of div2 (image), changing the transparency of the content nested within it.
I had a picture to make a transparent png, because this greatly increased the weight of the picture, which is not acceptable. Need to get back to version images to JPG.
How to make using JPG and save this DIV structure, to achieve transparency JPG, but without affecting the content that is embedded in it.

An example of how I don't like here (first section with background) - [Mobileindex.ru](http://mobileindex.ru)

Here we use transparent picture

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNPLwX

How to do the same thing only using the JPG picture
http://www.mobileindex.ru/images/background-mobileindex.ru.jpg  - without transparency

An important point - the content inside the DIV.parallax1 must extend the entire block height

```css
    .parallax-1 {

        width: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mobileindex.ru/images/Background-800-transp-mobileindex.ru.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        height: inherit;
        padding: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .gradient1 {


        height: 100vh auto;
        background: #6e72b6;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6e72b6 0%, #6d9594 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6e72b6 0%, #6d9594 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6e72b6 0%, #6d9594 100%);
        filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6e72b6', endColorstr='#6d9594', GradientType=0);
    }
    p {
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<div class="gradient1">
<div class="parallax-1">
    <p>bootstrap grid and contenr</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: check out [this template](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB02K3KK3) maybe it helps you

Comment: Please include the relevant code snippets in the question formatted as code blocks. Not your entire project, just the relevant code, likely a few lines of CSS and HTML in this case.

Comment: added  asdfdasfdsafsdf